# How do I make this param converter work?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Using Symfony2/Doctrine ORM**

I have an entity "ProductCategory".

**ProductCategory** ( fields )

- id (int)
- displayName (string)

I'm wanting to create a route with param converters. This is what I have. According to the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) it should work.

```
/**
  * @Route("/products/{category_name}")
  * @ParamConverter("c", class="AppBundle:ProductCategory", options={"mapping": { "displayName" = "category_name"}})
  */
public function viewProductPageAction(ProductCategory $c)
{
    return $this->render('templates/view-product.html.twig');
}
```

So what's going on up there? I want to convert the route key "**category_name**" to a **ProductCategory** entity by it's field **DisplayName** and assign it to **$c**.

Seems easy enough. Assign the category_name to the displayName field in the mapping option. But I'm getting this error.

> Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information. 500 - Logic exception

What is the reason I'm getting the error, and how am I misinterpreting the documentation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you were close enough. Arguments passed to `mapping` are in reversed order. The right syntax you're looking for here is like this:

```
/**
  * @Route("/products/{category_name}")
  * @ParamConverter("c", class="AppBundle:ProductCategory", options={"mapping": { "category_name" = "displayName"}})
  */
```

Comment: I was just discovering this! And this is clearly stated in the documentation. Just an oversight on my part. Thanks for the response!